# Where can I find a compatible version of SSMS for SQL Server 2016 CTP?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2016

Microsoft seem to have many versions of SQL Server 2016 CTP available at a time to download, at only 2.5GB a piece, but only one version of SSMS 2016 CTP, and if your db engine is the wrong version for SSMS, they don't suggest another version of SSMS, but another bloody version of the actual engine. This is quite ridiculous. I have a trial version of Toad that easily connects to any nearly DB engine version.

My SQL Server engine version is:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (CTP3.0) - 13.0.700.242 (X64) 
Oct 26 2015 18:46:06 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Express Edition (64-bit)
    on Windows 10 Pro 6.3 <X64> (Build 10586: ) (Hypervisor)
```

Does anyone know where I can get a version of SSMS 2016 that is compatible with this version?

The version of SSMS I have is the one downloaded from Rob Klimes's link in his comment below. It is version v13.0.800.111. When I try and run it, it shows me this:

[image]

The log file is large, and I don't know which parts are relevant enough to post here, but I don't see any glaring errors.

Comment: If you've downloaded the CTP, then just install Management Tools from there. There is no point in downloading the standalone SSMS during the CTP period, because SSMS and the CTPs are refreshed on the same monthly schedule. The behavior you're experiencing is a bug that has been reported many times and it should be addressed in CTP 3.2. Where are you seeing many versions of the CTP? If you go to the evaluation center, you should only see 3.1.

Comment: Where do I find SSMS then? I installed everything when I did the install, including management tools, but can't find the actual SSMS app anywhere?

Comment: If that error is from running the SSMS preview installation you do have to uninstall the previous version, that also applies to SQL Server CTP database engine and other components. I don't think the CTP installation media does upgrades or side-by-side installs.

Comment: CTP installation should upgrade the client tools just fine. Did you search your system for ssms.exe? Also, go back to the evaluation center and get CTP 3.1 (13.0.801).

Answer (score 2):

The SSMS November 2015 preview works against the SQL Server 2016 CTP versions. I actually use this version of SSMS (November 2015 preview) against my local 2012 and 2008 R2 instances and don't have any problems.

Comment: you can download it here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx

Comment: @BobKlimes Please see my edit as to what happens when I try that version.

Comment: The link @BobKlimes gave is kept up to date with recent versions; right now, it's the March 2016 release of SSMS.

Answer (score 1):

If you select to install Management Tools with the main CTP server install, you will find Management Studio located at:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe
```

or wherever your x86 program files are located.

*I had totally overlooked searching the x86 folders.*